# iPhone Set Auto Resizing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to set the auto-resizing on a subclass of a navigation bar, and a segmented control.  I need to do this in code, and not interface builder.

I want the code equivalent of this interface setup.

[image]

Edit:

I have tried this, but it does not work.

```
[self.segmentedControl setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
```

Comment: @JacquesCousteau check the edit.  Please note that did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5) notes:

> The flexible width and height constants [`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`] from the preceding figure have the same behavior as the width and size indicators in the Autosizing controls diagram. However, the behavior and use of margin indicators is effectively reversed. In Interface Builder, the presence of a margin indicator means that the margin has a fixed size and the absence of the indicator means the margin has a flexible size.

You want the bottom, left, and right margins to be *fixed* (which is the default), and the *top* margin to be flexible. Try this:

```
[self.segmentedControl setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
```